# Javascript Promise explicit return after reject

Tags: javascript, promise

In modern Javascript, we have something called Promises. We can use `reject` and `resolve` inside Promise.

My question is: do I need to return explicitly after calling `reject` or `resolve` inside Promise? So something like this:

```
function foo() {
  ...
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ...
    if (err) {
      reject(err);
      // return;
    }

    if (httpResponse.statusCode === 200) {
      resolve(httpResponse);
      // return;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Yes, unless you wrap the rest of the code in an `else` statement you need the `return` to avoid checking the statusCode even if you got an error.

Comment: Ok. I'm closing the question now.

Comment: oops.. already closed :)

Answer (score -2):

> My question is: do I need to return explicitly after calling reject or
>   resolve inside Promise? So something like this:

No, you don't need a return statement.

From [Mozilla Developer Network's Promises article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise):

**Syntax**

```
new Promise( /* executor */ function(resolve, reject) { ... } );
```

As you can see, no mention of any return statements.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks. I am new to this site. Will update answer.